# Server not responding to 'Socket.BeginReceive'

Tags: c#, sockets

**My problem:** When the client attempts to connect to the server via `Socket.BeginReceive`, the server is unresponsive. I've tried incorporating a `try/catch` block, but that's proved useless. And even in the VS debugger, instead of giving me an error log, it just goes into the Windows 7 "Program not responding" screen.

It doesn't happen all the time...only after approximately 5 or 6 successful connects and disconnects.

Here is the relevant code (server side, since the crash happens server side):

```
public Remote(Socket s)
{
    tempbuffer = new byte[300];
    buffer = new byte[0];
    connectionSocket = s;
    ip = connectionSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
    Log(ip + " connecting...");

    connectionSocket.BeginReceive(
        tempbuffer, 0, tempbuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(Receive), this);
}
```

Receive method:

```
static void Receive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Remote r = (Remote)result.AsyncState;
    if (r.disconnected) return;

    try
    {
        int length = r.connectionSocket.EndReceive(result);
        if (length == 0) { r.Disconnect(); return; }

        byte[] b = new byte[r.buffer.Length + length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(r.buffer, 0, b, 0, r.buffer.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(r.tempbuffer, 0, b, r.buffer.Length, length);

        r.buffer = r.HandleMessage(b);

        r.connectionSocket.BeginReceive(
            r.tempbuffer, 0, r.tempbuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                new AsyncCallback(Receive), r);
    }
    catch (SocketException) { r.Disconnect("Error!"); }
    catch (Exception e) { ErrorLog(e); r.Disconnect("Error!"); }
}
```

I see the `ip connecting` message, but then after that it is unresponsive. The `Receive` method is never called when it does that.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: It's too little code to figure out what might be wrong. Also, if you set a breakpoint in `Receive`, does it get called?

Comment: Are you calling the corresponding `EndReceive`?  I'm wondering if you are opening so many connections (and not closing them) that the server stops responding to new requests...

Comment: When the program is hung, break in the debugger and look at the `Threads` view.
You're *always* supposed to call `EndReceive`; you shouldn't bother checking `r.disconnected`. Instead of trying to futz with byte buffers yourself, use a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are giving it an invalid IP and Port to connect or the implementation for async receiving is just repeating something forever.

Comment: That's a blatant guess based on no evidence.  Poor answer.